# RTL8821AE wifi loses internet connection after some time

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet, asus

I installed Ubuntu as my main OS recently. It's very nice. Nevertheless I have some problems.

When I turned the computer on, the wifi connection worked perfectly. But after a few minutes, problems appeared. I was still connected to the wifi but with no Internet connection. And after a while, the connection with my router was lost.

I had been rebooting my laptop several times, but with the same results.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1b9a:2482]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

It's an Asus FX555UA.

Comment: Reboot your router as well but before make sure the wireless encryption is set to WPA2-AES. If the problem persists please [edit] you question, post that information along with the results of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`.